# Wordpress Gallery shortcode: Display one category ID only

Tags: shortcode, gallery

Good Day. I am using a Gallery shortcode in my wordpress site to display images. 
Problem is that I wasnt the gallery to show only images from a certain category, for example category id 35. How do I specify it in the shortcode?

Shortcode:

```
 [custom_gallery style="1" source="**cat=%cat_id%**" link="image" description="0" size="200x200" limit="10"]
```

Now I have tried the following, but does not work -

```
cat=%35%
cat=%cat_id=35%
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

SHORTCODE code:

```
/**
 * Gallery posts shortcode
 */

function gallery_posts_func($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "limit" => '5',
        "cat" => '',
        "thumb_width" => '',
        "thumb_height" => '',
    ), $atts));
    global $wp_query,$paged,$post;
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();

    $query .= '&posts_per_page='.$limit;
    $query .= '&post_type=gallery';
    $query .= '&taxonomy=gallery_cat';
    $query .= '&gallery_cat='.$cat;

    $wp_query->query($query);
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="gallery-holder fourthcol shortcode">
<?php

                $gogo_gallery_video_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_gallery_video_url', true);
                $gogo_gallery_links_to = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_gallery_links_to', true);
                $gogo_gallery_title_links_to = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_gallery_title_links_to', true);
                $gogo_gallery_custom_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_gallery_custom_link', true);

                if ($gogo_gallery_title && $gogo_gallery_video_url && $gogo_gallery_title_links_to=="gallery_title_links_image") {
                echo '<h5>';    
                echo '<a href="'.$gogo_gallery_video_url.'" rel="prettyPhoto[mixed]">';
                echo ''.get_the_title().'';
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</h5>';

                } elseif ($gogo_gallery_title && $gogo_gallery_title_links_to=="gallery_title_links_image") {
                echo '<h5>';    
                echo '<a href="'.$thumbnail[0].'" rel="prettyPhoto[mixed]">';
                echo ''.get_the_title().'';
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</h5>';

                } elseif ($gogo_gallery_title && $gogo_gallery_title_links_to=="gallery_title_links_content") {
                echo '<h5>';    
                echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
                echo ''.get_the_title().'';
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</h5>';

                } elseif ($gogo_gallery_title && $gogo_gallery_title_links_to=="gallery_title_links_link") {
                echo '<h5>';    
                echo '<a href="'.$gogo_gallery_custom_link.'">';
                echo ''.get_the_title().'';
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</h5>';

                } elseif ($gogo_gallery_title) {
                echo '<h5>';    
                echo ''.get_the_title().'';
                echo '</h5>';

                } else {
                echo '';
                }
        ?>  
<div class="gallery-box">
    <div class="gallery-image prettygallery">
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
            <?php
                $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');

                if ($gogo_gallery_video_url && $gogo_gallery_links_to=="gallery_links_image") { 
                echo '<a href="'.$gogo_gallery_video_url.'" rel="prettyPhoto[mixed]">';
                echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/timthumb.php?src='.$thumbnail[0].'&amp;w='.$thumb_width.'&amp;h='.$thumb_height.'&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100&amp;s=1" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
                echo '</a>';

                } elseif ($gogo_gallery_links_to=="gallery_links_image") {
                echo '<a href="'.$thumbnail[0].'" rel="prettyPhoto[mixed]">';
                echo '<img   src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/timthumb.php?src='.$thumbnail[0].'&amp;w='.$thumb_width.'&amp;h='.$thumb_height.'&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100&amp;s=1" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
                echo '</a>';

                } elseif ($gogo_gallery_links_to=="gallery_links_content") {
                echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
                echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/timthumb.php?src='.$thumbnail[0].'&amp;w='.$thumb_width.'&amp;h='.$thumb_height.'&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100&amp;s=1" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
                echo '</a>';

                } elseif ($gogo_gallery_links_to=="gallery_links_link") {
                echo '<a href="'.$gogo_gallery_custom_link.'">';
                echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/timthumb.php?src='.$thumbnail[0].'&amp;w='.$thumb_width.'&amp;h='.$thumb_height.'&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100&amp;s=1" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
                echo '</a>';

                } else {
                echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/timthumb.php?src='.$thumbnail[0].'&amp;w='.$thumb_width.'&amp;h='.$thumb_height.'&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100&amp;s=1" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
                }
            ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php if ($gogo_gallery_short_desc) { ?><em><?php echo $gogo_gallery_short_desc; ?></em><?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>


    <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode("gallery_posts", "gallery_posts_func");
```

Comment: The default gallery shortcode for wordpress is [gallery]. So I suppose your shortcode [custom_gallery] is just what it sounds like: a custom shortcode.

Without knowing from which plugin this comes from (maybe even a custom coding in functions.php?) it's hard to help.

Comment: Can you post the Code for your shortcode? It is impossible to tell just from the shortcode.

Comment: ok will post it. Thanks people, appreciate your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do..

```
[custom_gallery style="1" cat="35" link="image" description="0" size="200x200" limit="10"]
```

Comment: Hi Rajeev - Thank you for your answer, but I tried this, and does not work - I get this message:Custom gallery: "no attached images, or only one attached image…"  - and cat 35 does have images

Comment: I made a mistake. I referenced the wrong cat. It works. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer. As I wrote, I kept noticing more and more issues or potential issues. Rather than waste the effort, here is what I have and I hope it helps.

First, you are registering your shortcode as `gallery_posts` but are using `custom_gallery` to try to implement it.

You are passing your category like this: `source="**cat=%cat_id%**"` but you aren't doing any further processing so this line: `$query .= '&gallery_cat='.$cat;` never actually gets set, and if it did it would end up looking like this: `$query .= '&gallery_cat=**cat=%cat_id%**`, which would be wrong. The attribute name/ID is `source` but you don't use that. You use `cat` instead.

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "limit" => '5',
    "cat" => '',
    "thumb_width" => '',
    "thumb_height" => '',
), $atts));
```

I would suggest something like this for your shortcode:

```
[custom_gallery style="1" cat="35" ...
```

(No idea why you have all those `%` in your code, not to mention the `*`. What are those supposed to be doing?) Now this line-- `$query .= '&gallery_cat='.$cat;`--  will come out like `$query .= '&gallery_cat=35`, but [if you check the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), that (deprecated) `{tax}=` syntax expects a slug, not an ID. You need to rewrite your query like this:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => $limit,
  'post_type' => 'gallery',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'gallery_cat',
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => $cat
    )
  )
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

That should clear up some problems at least. I should note that 'gallery' is not a post a type that I am aware of. I assume this is something you created? If you are trying to use the WordPress galleries, that is not going to work. Take a look at how the WordPress gallery shortcode pulls data: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/media.php#L671 It isn't a simple process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Appreciate. using cat="35" worked just fine

Comment: If that worked then the code you posted isn't accurate. For one, the name of the shortcode is different, as mentioned. I tried to run you code as is and the shortcode isn't processed at all. The string is spit back out just as it went in. That is why I noticed that issue. Secondly, even if it works you are using deprecated code, and it has been deprecated for awhile. It will eventually stop working.